# Plotting a graph against the days of week in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a column named `date` in my data frame and another column named `values`. I want to plot the values against the days of a week.

I know that we can get days of a week from date by using the function `weekdays()`. But I am not sure about how to plot the graph with `values`(y-axis) against the days of week(x-axis)

```
      Date  Values
12-03-2006     0.5
14-03-2006     0.6
18-03-2006     0.9
23-03-2006     1.1
02-04-2006     2.1
```

I tried this

```
plot(weekdays(df$Date),df$values)
```

I got this error :

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this error?

Comment: I think your Date column is not in a correct `Date` format. Try changing it beforehand with `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: I have done that in my code. The error is still there when I am trying to plot.

Comment: When you run `class(weekdays(df$Date))` you will notice that it is of `character` class. What you need to transform it to a factor or ordered factor. So running this code `plot(as.factor(weekdays(df$Date)), df$Values)` will plot the graph as required. You can rearrange the levels using `levels` to get it to the correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the `weekdays(df$date)` to a factor before you plot it.

```
df$Date <- as.factor(weekdays(df$Date))
```

will make it a factor and hence you can use it to plot now. `plot(df$Date,df$Values)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column with days names eg: 'day_of_week'

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(day_of_week = weekdays(Date))
```

... and use factor function with levels to choose desired order of days.

```
df$Date <- factor(df$Date, levels = c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'))
```